# Cannot modify the field in recursive structure

Tags: rust

I have a recursive structure, where field of a structure is a reference to other struct of same type:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct RecursiveStruct<'a> {
    outer: Option<Box<&'a RecursiveStruct<'a>>>,
    dict: HashMap<u32, String>
}
```

With this structure I also have couple of methods such as constructor, method which adds (k,v) pair to calee's field and a getter:

```
impl<'a> RecursiveStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new(outer: Option<Box<&'a RecursiveStruct<'a>>>) -> Self {
        let dict: HashMap<u32, String> = HashMap::new();
        RecursiveStruct { outer, dict }
    }
    
    // searches for value corresponding to key in all struct layers
    pub fn get(&self, key: u32) -> Result<String, ()> {
        let item = self.dict.get(&key);
        match item {
            Some(x) => Ok(x.clone()),
            None => {
                match &self.outer {
                    Some(x) => x.get(key),
                    None => Err(())
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // adds (key, val) to "innermost" instance of struct
    pub fn add(&mut self, key:u32, val: String) {
        self.dict.insert(key, val);
    }
}
```

These methods work fine, but when I try to add a method, which tries to modify `dict` field in any of the inner layers, I get `cannot borrow '***x' as mutable, as it is behind a '&' reference` error.

```
pub fn re_assign(&mut self, key: u32, val: String) {
    if self.dict.contains_key(&key) {
        self.dict.insert(key, val);
    } else {
        match &mut self.outer {
            Some(x) => x.re_assign(key, val.clone()),
            None => println!("Such key couldn't be found!"),
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d59ff0efb08a75d91258c3b429230ab) to playground.

Comment: Why are you using a `Box<& T>` That is usually a code smell. Is there a specific reason you want a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: I am using `Box<T>` since I thought that was the only way to implement recursive structures in Rust. As for reference, I wanted to avoid that at all costs (since I am not too familiar with lifetimes),but I am trying to implement a scoping for a programming language here. I really don't want to clone/copy whole outer scopes each time I initialize a new scope.

Comment: You can have an `&` in a recursive data structure. Replace your `Box<& T>` with an `&mut` and that will probably simplify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a &, but want a &mut, rust references are immutable by default:
Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be82b8ba01dff60e106af9e59df8228e

```rs
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct RecursiveStruct<'a> {
    outer: Option<Box<&'a mut RecursiveStruct<'a>>>,
    dict: HashMap<u32, String>
}

impl<'a> RecursiveStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new(outer: Option<Box<&'a mut RecursiveStruct<'a>>>) -> Self {
        let dict: HashMap<u32, String> = HashMap::new();
        RecursiveStruct { outer, dict }
    }
    
    pub fn get(&self, key: u32) -> Result<String, ()> {
        let item = self.dict.get(&key);
        match item {
            Some(x) => Ok(x.clone()),
            None => {
                match &self.outer {
                    Some(x) => x.get(key),
                    None => Err(())
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    pub fn re_assign(&mut self, key: u32, val: String) {
        if self.dict.contains_key(&key) {
            self.dict.insert(key, val);
        } else {
            match &mut self.outer {
                Some(x) => x.re_assign(key, val.clone()),
                None => println!("Such key couldn't be found!"),
            };
        }
    }
    
    pub fn add(&mut self, key:u32, val: String) {
        self.dict.insert(key, val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // instantiate "outer" struct and set its field
    let mut S = RecursiveStruct::new(None);
    S.add(42, "Answer to the universe!".to_string());
    // instantiate "inner" struct
    let mut S1 = RecursiveStruct::new(Some(Box::new(&mut S)));
    println!("{}", S1.get(42).unwrap()); // get the field of outer struct
    // modify the field of outer struct
    S1.re_assign(42, "The answer has been changed.".to_string());
    println!("{}", S1.get(42).unwrap());
}
```